# Are there any tools that can help me read c++ template compiling errors?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deciphering C++ template error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980/deciphering-c-template-error-messages)

everytime I get this kind of template error message:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/mpl/set/aux_/iterator.hpp:19:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mpl/set/aux_/begin_end_impl.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mpl/set/set0.hpp:29,
                 from /usr/include/boost/parameter/aux_/set.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/include/boost/parameter/parameters.hpp:48,
                 from /usr/include/boost/accumulators/framework/accumulator_set.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/include/boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp:12,
                 from src/SimMany.cpp:4:
/usr/include/boost/mpl/has_key.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::mpl::has_key<mpl_::arg<1>, mpl_::ar
g<2> >’:
/usr/include/boost/mpl/if.hpp:67:11:   instantiated from ‘boost::mpl::if_<boost::mpl::has_key<mpl_:
:arg<1>, mpl_::arg<2> >, boost::mpl::identity<mpl_::arg<1> >, boost::mpl::insert<mpl_::arg<1>, boos
t::mpl::pair<mpl_::arg<2>, mpl_::arg<2> >, mpl_::na> >’
/usr/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:37:41:   instantiated from ‘boost::mpl::eval_if<boost::mpl::has_
key<mpl_::arg<1>, mpl_::arg<2> >, boost::mpl::identity<mpl_::arg<1> >, boost::mpl::insert<mpl_::arg
<1>, boost::mpl::pair<mpl_::arg<2>, mpl_::arg<2> >, mpl_::na> >’
/usr/include/boost/accumulators/framework/depends_on.hpp:330:9:   instantiated from ‘boost::accumul
ators::detail::insert_feature<mpl_::arg<1>, mpl_::arg<2> >’
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/template_arity.hpp:85:5:   instantiated from ‘const in
t boost::mpl::aux::template_arity_impl<boost::accumulators::detail::insert_feature<mpl_::arg<1>, mp
l_::arg<2> >, 1>::value’
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/template_arity.hpp:93:5:   instantiated from ‘const in
t boost::mpl::aux::template_arity<boost::accumulators::detail::insert_feature<mpl_::arg<1>, mpl_::a
rg<2> > >::value’
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/template_arity.hpp:98:30:   [ skipping 2 instantiation
 contexts ]
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/apply.hpp:73:1:   instantiated from ‘boost::mpl::apply
2<boost::mpl::if_<boost::mpl::is_sequence<mpl_::arg<2> >, boost::accumulators::detail::insert_seque
nce<mpl_::arg<1>, mpl_::arg<2>, void>, boost::accumulators::detail::insert_feature<mpl_::arg<1>, mp
l_::arg<2> > >, boost::mpl::map0<>, boost::accumulators::tag::mean>’
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/fold_impl.hpp:166:1:   instantiated from ‘boost::mpl::
aux::fold_impl<-0x00000000000000001, boost::mpl::aux::transform_iter<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::accu
mulators::stats<boost::accumulators::tag::mean, boost::accumulators::tag::variance(boost::accumulat
ors::lazy)>, 0l>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::accumulators::stats<boost::accumulators::tag::mean, boo
st::accumulators::tag::variance(boost::accumulators::lazy)>, 2l>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::b
ind1<boost::mpl::quote1<boost::accumulators::as_feature, mpl_::void_>, mpl_::arg<1> >, 0> >, boost:
:mpl::aux::transform_iter<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::accumulators::stats<boost::accumulators::tag::m
ean, boost::accumulators::tag::variance(boost::accumulators::lazy)>, 2l>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost:
:accumulators::stats<boost::accumulators::tag::mean, boost::accumulators::tag::variance(boost::accu
mulators::lazy)>, 2l>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::bind1<boost::mpl::quote1<boost::accumulators
::as_feature, mpl_::void_>, mpl_::arg<1> >, 0> >, boost::mpl::map0<>, boost::mpl::if_<boost::mpl::i
s_sequence<mpl_::arg<2> >, boost::accumulators::detail::insert_sequence<mpl_::arg<1>, mpl_::arg<2>,
 void>, boost::accumulators::detail::insert_feature<mpl_::arg<1>, mpl_::arg<2> > > >’
/usr/include/boost/mpl/fold.hpp:39:18:   instantiated from ‘boost::mpl::fold<boost::accumulators::d
etail::as_feature_list<boost::accumulators::stats<boost::accumulators::tag::mean, boost::accumulato
rs::tag::variance(boost::accumulators::lazy)>, void>, boost::mpl::map0<>, boost::mpl::if_<boost::mp
l::is_sequence<mpl_::arg<2> >, boost::accumulators::detail::insert_sequence<mpl_::arg<1>, mpl_::arg
<2>, void>, boost::accumulators::detail::insert_feature<mpl_::arg<1>, mpl_::arg<2> > > >’
/usr/include/boost/accumulators/framework/depends_on.hpp:370:13:   instantiated from ‘boost::accumu
lators::detail::make_accumulator_tuple<boost::accumulators::stats<boost::accumulators::tag::mean, b
oost::accumulators::tag::variance(boost::accumulators::lazy)>, double, void>’
/usr/include/boost/accumulators/framework/accumulator_set.hpp:122:5:   instantiated from ‘boost::ac
cumulators::accumulator_set<double, boost::accumulators::stats<boost::accumulators::tag::mean, boos
t::accumulators::tag::variance(boost::accumulators::lazy)> >’
src/SimMany.cpp:70:7:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/mpl/has_key.hpp:33:1: error: no class template named ‘apply’ in ‘struct boost::m
pl::has_key_impl<boost::mpl::non_sequence_tag>’
```

I get reaaaaaaally lost. I can't even  visually parse where one error message starts and another ends. Are there any dev tools that can help me with this?

This gets particularly scary when I'm using boost libraries. :(

Comment: I think clang claims to produce more sensible error messages.

Comment: normally, I look at the first line ("instanciated from...") and the last (the real error) - there should be enough information there to start figuring out what's going on... everything in the middle is noise IMHO....

Answer (score 2):

[STLFilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html) or use different compiler. Clang has supposedly better error messages (I cannot tell for sure, I didn't used it personally)