# adapter pattern : support underlying data that can be const or non-const, elegantly

Tags: c++, function, constants, adapter, c++14

How to make an adapter class to support both const and non-const underlying data appropriately?

## Concrete Example

`RigidBody` is a class describing physic property of object.
Here is its very simplified version (1D):-

```
class RigidBody{
    float position=1;
    public: float getPosition()const{ return position;}
    public: void setPosition(float ppos){ position=ppos;}
};
```

`Adapter` encapsulates `RigidBody`.
It provides *a-little-distorted* functionality to `get/set position`:-

```
class Adapter{
    public: RigidBody* rigid; int offset=2;
    public: float getPosition(){
        return rigid->getPosition()+offset;     //distort
    }
    public: void setPosition(float ppos){
        return rigid->setPosition(ppos-offset); //distort
    }
};
```

I can set position of `RigidBody` indirectly by using `Adapter` :-

```
int main() {
    RigidBody rigid;
    Adapter adapter;  //Edit: In real life, this type is a parameter of many function
    adapter.rigid=&rigid;
    adapter.setPosition(5);
    std::cout<<adapter.getPosition();//print 5
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/523aed808aeb844b)).

## Objective

I want create a new function that receives **`const`**`RigidBody* rigid`.
I should be able to read from it (e.g. `getPosition()`) by using adapter.

However, I don't really know how to do it elegantly.

```
void test(const RigidBody* rigid){
    Adapter adapter2; 
    //adapter2.rigid=rigid; //not work, how to make it work?
    //adapter2.setPosition(5); //should not work
    //adapter2.getPosition();  //should work 
}
```

## My poor solutions

### Solution A1 (2 adapters + 1 widget)

Create a widget :-

```
class AdapterWidget{
    public: static Adapter createAdapter(RigidBody* a);
    public: static AdapterConst createAdapter(const RigidBody* a);
};
```

`AdapterConst` can only `getPosition()`, while `AdapterConst` can both get and set.

I can use it like :-

```
void test(const RigidBody* rigid){
    auto adapter=AdapterWidget::createAdapter(rigid);
```

It is easy to use.

**Disadvantage:** Code of  `AdapterConst` and `Adapter` will be very duplicated.

### Solution A2 (+inheritance)

It is an improvement of the previous solution.
Let `Adapter` (has `setPosition()`) derive from `AdapterConst` (has `getPosition()`).

**Disadvantage:** It is not concise.  I use 2 classes for the single task!
This might seem to be trivial, but in a bigger code-base, it is not fun at all.

Specifically, location of `getPosition()` will be far-away from `setPosition()`, e.g in different files.
This causes maintainability problem.

### Solution B (template)

Create a template class.  There are many ways e.g. :-

- `Adapter<T   =RigidBody        OR    const RigidBody    >`
- `Adapter<bool=true is const    OR    false is non-const >`

**Disadvantage:** In every ways, it is inelegant.  It is an overkill. (?)
I will suffer from disadvantage of template e.g. everything in header.

### Solution C1 (const_cast)

I am trying to avoid it.   [It is evil.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498292/c-why-is-const-cast-evil)

```
class Adapter{
    public: RigidBody* rigid; 
    void setUnderlying(const RigidBody* r){
        rigid=const_cast< RigidBody*>(r);
    }
    ....
};
```

### Solution C2 (+manual assert)

I can add some assertion manually.
It just emphasizes how much it is unprofessional :-

```
    bool isConst;
    void setUnderlying(const RigidBody* r){
        ...
        isConst=true;
    }
    void setUnderlying(RigidBody* r){
        ...
        isConst=false;
    }
    void setPosition(float a){
        if(isConst){ /*throw some exception*/ }
        ....
    }
```

### Solution D (run away)

- **Lazy :** change from `test(`**`const`**`RigidBody* rigid)` to `test(RigidBody* rigid)`.
- **Crazy :** change `RigidBody::setPosition()` to be `const`.

In either way, my program will not be `const`-correct any more,
but a single `Adapter` class would be enough.

## Question

Do I really have to do one of these things wherever I encounter the const/non-const pattern?
Please provide a pretty solution. (no full code is required, but I don't mind)

Sorry for the long post.

**Edit:**  In real life, `Adapter` is a parameter for many function.
It is passed around like a toy.

Most of such functions don't have knowledge about `RigidBody`, so it is not quite suitable to change from a bundle calling `someFunction(adapter)` to `someFunction(offset,rigidbody)`.

Comment: Instead of having `Adapter` as a class with a member pointing to a `RigidBody` it doesn't manage, why not just have two freestanding functions `void setPostition(RigidBody *body, const float& pos)` and `float getPosition(const RigidBody *body)` ? Even better, pass by RigidBody reference.

Comment: @Jamie Bullock  An interesting idea... If so, how the adapter's function (get/set) would be implemented?  How it can solve the problem?  ....... Do you mean a different design pattern?

Comment: Am I missing something or you need type erasure like `std::variant<RigidBody*, const RigidBody*>` available since c++17?

Comment: @W.F.  I have never heard about [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).  Thank.   I think this is a very basic (?) question, so I didn't really expect that I need such a luxuriant feature.

Comment: Your code tries to much to adhere to Java conventions and ideas. I don't even think you need an Adapter.

Comment: I think boost provides variant before c++17 as well. Luxuriant or not you want some type erasure I guess, as long of course as the information about constness of an underlying object can be supplied at runtime (because template base solution here might be misleading)...

Comment: @David Haim   possible!  It is hard for me to judge what is Java-like because it is inside my heart. ....  I want to make usage as easy as possible, and I can't find any thing easier to use than `adapter->getPosition()` (no parameter yea!).

Comment: @JamieBullock your free function would also need an offset parameter. I this warrents a class

Comment: very simple [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vuOz8xkMiOMhPSN9) of `std::variant` testing constness qualifiers of underlying object...

Comment: @javaLover yes it's a different pattern, see: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197 on why to prefer non-member non-friend functions. As Caleth pointed out, there is the offset parameter to deal with, in which case you could make both the functions I mentioned members of `Adapter` and have them take a `RigidBody&` and `const RigidBody&` as their first argument respectively rather than storing a bare pointer on `Adapter`

Comment: @W.F. Thank.  It is still hard for me to see its full benefit.  AFAIK, it is a kind of union.  It provides no assertion.   Thus, its pro/con is similar to `const_cast`, right?

Comment: @Jamie Bullock That is a legendary link for me.  I had read it several times.  XD    .... By the way, the proposed solution is harder to use.  `Adapter::getPosition(const RigidBody& )` is painful.

Comment: @javaLover well maybe, but IMO it makes the intent clearer: i) the thing you are getting the position of "is a" `RigidBody` and not an `Adapter` ii) the caller is responsible for the lifetime of the `RigidBody` instance and you don't risk a dangling pointer

Comment: @javaLover the getter could benefit from visitor pattern while setter would test non const at run-time ... [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/623dFusc6hAk8LHt)

Comment: @W.F. Now, I feel it can be a superior improvement from C2 (better encapsulated).  I can't access to C++17 in real life, so I've got to find a way without it.    After read it several times, I got some rough new idea. (Wasting CPU from runs-time check is not too bad, because it can be disabled by creating a custom macro.)  Thank a lot.

Comment: @javaLover if you plan to use it where the run-time efficiency do matter you could also consider storing both `RigidBody* rigid;` and `const RigidBody* c_rigid; ` and overload `rigid` setter for const version which sets `rigid=nullptr;`. Now in position value getter you would use the const field and in setter the non-const one (which checks for rigid existance first)...

Comment: If your solutions are complete and correct, this question may be better posed over at [codereview.se] as a `[comarative-review]`. Be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as it's a little different over there!

Comment: @Toby Speight Thank, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't keep with that idea. This is C++, not Java.

Your code is extremely Java oriented. I can see it by the way you write the code, use pointers and silently omit `const` when needed.

In fact, most of the bad C++ code that I personally saw is pretty much either written to be "C inside classes" or "Java without GC". Both of them are extremely bad ways of writing C++ code.

Your question has an idiomatic solution:

1. Ditch most of the design patterns. they are useful for languages where object are reference types by default. C++ prefers most of the times to tread object as *value types* and prefer static polymorphism (templates) rather than run-time polymorphism (inherit + override).
2. Write two classes , one is `Adapter` and one is `ConstAdapter`. This is what the standard library already does. every container has different `iterator` and `const_iterator` implementation exactly because of that reason. you can either store something by pointer, either by const pointer. It is error prone trying to mix the two. If there were a nice solution for that problem, we wouldn't have two iterator typedefs for each container.

Comment: You are suggesting A1 or A2, right?  This makes me sad.  ... I am not sure what is "override" here (in a.).  There is no virtual function. .... I personally hate template, it increases my re-compile  time quite a lot.

Comment: @javaLover I was generally talking about templates vs base classes.

Comment: @DavidHaim I would argue with `completely no runtime polymorphism in c++` rule. If that was the case for the STL `std::function` wouldn't exist...

Comment: @W.F. I never claimed that.

Comment: @DavidHaim let me rephrase the comment - I think the power of the c++ is multi-paradigm. If someone finds runtime polymorphism efficient enough in his or her task... I'd say `go ahead!`

Comment: @javaLover: You hate recompilation times and I hate runtime errors! And stuff which can be checked at compile time being carried to runtime and bloated exception handlers. C++ has incredibly great static polymorphism, which can ensure that if the program compiles it than runs, runs very fast and without errors! To decrease compile times you should design a good architecture, keeping in mind language idioms. I suggest reading: Large Scale C++ Software Design by John Lakos and these idioms: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms. Carrying Java to C++ ends up with unmaintainable code.

Comment: @ovanes  While I agree with you that runtime errors worse than more recompilation time (partially cured by pimpl), there are 2 things I really dislike about template :- **1)** intellisense/context-clue partially stop working -> partially cure by using some expensive plugin  **2)** generally unreadable compile-error message (from my own mistake)  -> partially cure by [use other compilers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779521) .... Thank for the book.  It looks nice.

Answer (score 2):

A tightly controlled `const_cast` looks like a good solution to me:

```
// Only provides read-only access to the object
struct ConstAdapter {
    int offset = 2;

    // Constructible from const and non-const RigidBodies
    ConstAdapter(RigidBody const *rigid)
    : _rigid{rigid} { }

    // Read-only interface
    float getPosition() {
        return rigid()->getPosition() + offset;     //distort
    }

    // Hidden away for consistency with Adapter's API
    // and to prevent swapping out an "actually non-const" RigidBody
    // for a "truly const" one (see  Adapter::rigid()`).
    RigidBody const *rigid() const { return _rigid; }

private:
    RigidBody const *_rigid;
};

// Inherits read-only functions, and provides write access as well
struct Adapter : ConstAdapter {

    // Only constructible from a non-const RigidBody!
    Adapter(RigidBody *rigid) : ConstAdapter{rigid} { }

    // Write interface
    void setPosition(float ppos){
        return rigid()->setPosition(ppos-offset); //distort
    }

    // Here's the magic part: we know we can cast `const` away
    // from our base class' pointer, since we provided it ourselves
    // and we know it's not actually `const`.
    RigidBody *rigid() const {
        return const_cast<RigidBody *>(ConstAdapter::rigid());
    }
};
```

Regarding:

> Specifically, location of `getPosition()` will be far-away from `setPosition()`, e.g in different files.
>   This causes maintainability problem.

This is a non-issue. C++, unlike Java, allows multiple classes in a single file, and you are in fact encouraged to group such tightly related classes together. The declarations of the functions will be only a handful of lines apart, and their definitions can very well be grouped together in the corresponding `.cpp` file.

Comment: Oh thank, "their definitions can very well be grouped together" I totally forget this.

Answer (score 1):

Use references instead of pointers, and let the const-ness propogate to the `Adapter`. Then you can safely const_cast, as

```
template <class Rigid>
class Adapter{
    Rigid & rigid;
    int offset;
public: 
    Adapter(Rigid & rigid, int offset = 2) : rigid(rigid), offset(offset) {}
    float getPosition() const { return rigid.getPosition() + offset; }
    void setPosition(float ppos) { rigid.setPosition(ppos - offset); }
};
```

Comment: What is its advantage compared to my C1(const_cast - evil)?

Comment: You can't accidentally `setPosition` a const RigidBody, because you can only get const Adapters

Comment: I don't think so .... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0f3015d4ed20450   It is compilable ....  did I miss something?   The `&` might not *propagate* to the field in the way we think?

Comment: I've worked out what is going on there, auto is deducing Adaptor and there is an implicit copy

Comment: Yeah, returning a `const Adapter` from your factory method doesn't help, because it's just copy-constructing a non-const local.

Comment: I was working backwards from `template <class Rigid> class Adapter { Rigid & rigid; ... }`. Seems the template is neccecary

Comment: Yeah, that's sufficient - you don't even need to do anything clever on `setPosition`, you just won't be able to call it on `Adapter<const RigidBody>`.

Comment: @Caleth  After the editing, what is its advantage compared to my B?

Comment: brevity, mostly

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct would be to access a `RigidBody` through an `Adaptor` and a `const RigidBody` through a `const Adaptor`.  To achieve this, we use a factory to create the right kind of `Adaptor`, and in the implementation, we access the underlying `RigidBody` through an accessor method that (safely) casts only when allowed.

### The code:

Start with the private members:

```
class Adaptor
{
    RigidBody const& body;
    int offset;

    Adaptor(RigidBody body, int offset=2)
        : body(body),
          offset(offset)
    {}

    Adaptor(const Adaptor&) = delete;
```

The constructor is private, so we can only create instances through our factory.  And we remove the copy constructor, so we can't create a non-const `Adaptor` from a const one.

Next, we have our first overloaded pair - the accessor used in the implementation.  I've marked it `protected`, in case you want a range of similar adaptors.  It could safely be `public` if you want, though.

```
protected:
    RigidBody& get_body() { return const_cast<RigidBody&>(body); }
    RigidBody const& get_body() const { return body; }
```

We know that the `const_cast` is safe, because we only get a non-const `Adaptor` from a non-const `RigidBody`, as we see in the other overloaded pair, which is the factory:

```
public:
    static Adaptor *adapt(RigidBody& body, int offset = 2) { return new Adaptor{ body, offset }; }
    static Adaptor const *adapt(RigidBody const& body, int offset = 2) { return new Adaptor{ body, offset }; }
```

From here on, each method is declared const unless it needs to modify the body, just as you'd expect.  So, if you have a `const Adaptor` (which you will if you constructed it from a `const RigidBody`, you can't call any method that modifies `body`.  And the implementation can't modify `body` from within any of the `const` methods.

```
    float getPosition() const
    {
        // this uses the const get_body()
        return get_body().getPosition() + offset;
    }

    void setPosition(float ppos)
    {
        // this uses the mutable get_body()
        get_body().setPosition(ppos-offset);
    }
```

You can demonstrate the safety by trying to modify `body` in a const method:

```
   void illegal() const
   {
       get_body().setPosition(0); // error: passing ‘const RigidBody’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers
       body.setPosition(0);       // error: passing ‘const RigidBody’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers
   }

};
```

### Demo:

With a `RigidBody`, the adapter allows all operations; with a const `RigidBody`, the adapter allows only `const` operations:

```
#include <memory>
int main()
{
    {
        RigidBody b;
        std::unique_ptr<Adaptor> a{Adaptor::adapt(b)};
        a->setPosition(15.);
        a->getPosition();
    }

    {
        RigidBody const b;
        std::unique_ptr<const Adaptor> a{Adaptor::adapt(b)};
        a->setPosition(15.);     // error: passing ‘const Adaptor’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers
        a->getPosition();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the demo of this solution.  : http://ideone.com/eedaK6   .....  Can I avoid "new" (i.e. heap)?

Comment: It might be possible - but it's more difficult, as you need to be able to copy (or at least move-construct) the return value from the factory, without losing the constness.  I didn't see how to do it, but I'd love to see any suggestions.

Comment: Thank.  Your solution has some unique strong advantage.  .... You can put the demo link (e.g. copy my link) to your question if you want.  :)